# How to identify if a Chabad shul is Meshichist?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chabad, heresy, messianism

How can one discern whether a Chabad shul is [Meshichist](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabad_messianism)?

Comment: A lot of them will have mashichist pamphlets on the table, and stuff that refers to the Rebbe as Shlit"a.

Comment: @N.T. not necessarily an indication. Dvar Malchus for example has this on the cover b/c it uses the same cover from when it was originally printed.

Comment: @Dude I know. Although I think even the modern parts of dvar malchus say shlita.

Answer (score 5):

From what I have observed some will have the famous psak din  declaring the Rebba as Mashiach hung up in the shul.

Picture of psak din declaring the Rebba as Mashiach and making obligatory for everyone to accept:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The yellow [moshiach flag](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chabad_Mashiach_Flag.svg) is often proudly on display at such shuls

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118601/history-of-chabad-moshiach-flag?rq=1

Comment: the moshiach flag doesn't have to be specific to a meshichist shul

Comment: Interesting, @Dude. Meaning that there are non-meshichist shuls that display it as well?

Answer (score 3):

If they have a sign saying “yechi” or encourage it being said. Sometimes it will be on the cover of the Aron.

Answer (score 0):

Check their website or the entrance area of the shul. If the Rebbe is referred to with ztl or in loving memory or anything like that it's not. Also in regards to the guy who poated the fake picture of all the signatures, many of the names were forged and several rabbis on it said they never gave permission to put there names. It's a forged document. Further, even if real, it isn't halachically binding.

Comment: Thank you and welcome to the site!  Your initial advice is sensible.  If you can actually back up your forgery statement with evidence, this would be a much better answer, otherwise maybe you should [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/138387/edit) that part out.

Comment: I don't know how you would do that on the internet from public statements made by about half of those rabbis around the time that that letter was put out.... You're welcome to contact them at least half will tell you that they didn't sign it. Several of those who did said that they were wrong. There is a reason the chabad movement is a whole does not have that as philosophy officially or say that the document is official and real. I'm happy to list some of the rabbis I remember saying it publicly and a few that I've heard say it themselves when I asked them years after the fact.